# push notification to mobile devices: SNS vs OneSignal vs GCM

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns, onesignal

Our use case for mobile push involves the following
a) pro-grammatically register all mobile devices on the devices (SNS documentation says we have to register the mobile device with the topic, without mentioning programmatic registration(?))

b)we have the website that shows all the users. when clicked on any user icon on the website, it should send `automatically/pro-grammatically` send mobile push to that particular device. It appears GCM only supports sending mobile push from firebase account and can't be integrated into HTML/js code base (?)

c)support both Android and iOS based devices

d)support users worldwide

e)restart the app, without user interaction or opening the notification,  if it is not running (that is auto restart the app)

I am aware of the following link (seems outdated)
[Push notifications: Why use Amazon SNS over Google's GCM/FCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184521/push-notifications-why-use-amazon-sns-over-googles-gcm-fcm?rq=1)

Any suggestions if `GCM` or one signal or SNS is the right technology for the above requirements

Comment: Use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) instead. more preferred now a days over GCM

Comment: your question is opinion-based. Only answer you can get is `I think that ... is better`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chose to go with GCM/FCM. More or less it supports all the above features
(I am answering my own question, since there was no response)