# Why should I combine SNS and Firebase GCM

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I have very little experience with Push Notifications.
I'm researching how to integrate some services, AWS or Firebase.
My infrastructure will be AWS for the rest of the services but what could be a difference between choosing AWS SNS or having both together?

Is there a specific reason to use both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push notifications: Why use Amazon SNS over Google's GCM/FCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184521/push-notifications-why-use-amazon-sns-over-googles-gcm-fcm)

Comment: Fixed some grammar and layout.